# cifs mount differences: mount command vs fstab entry

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I am experiencing a difference between two methods of mounting a volume. If I use mount at the command line:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=ntlmssp,vers=1.0,credentials=/home/bob/.credentials,uid=1001,gid=1001 //192.168.20.16/bob /home/bob/home`

then all is good. If however I use a (what I believe to be identical) fstab entry:

`//192.186.20.16/bob /home/bob/home cifs sec=ntlmssp,vers=1.0,credentials=/home/bob/.credentials  0   0`

Then I get the following failure:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

dmesg helpfully tells me:

```
[ 1406.873877] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[ 1406.873906] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

I don't believe I have the path wrong - as the command line forsion to the exact same path works - so I think the no such file or directory is a misnomer. The error code is [saying something similar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cifs/8f11e0f3-d545-46cc-97e6-f00569e3e1bc?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but I can't believe that either.

Any help would be greatly appriciated as my current workaround of a startup script to run the command line version makes me sad! (This is after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, moving over my previous working setup.)